# Copy a list of file in a text file to a folder, using python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, copy, backup

I have a .txt file with a number of files. 
On each line in the .txt file is there is a full path to a file.

How to copy and dump the files into a folder i.e. /home/admin

Comment: any attempts you'd like to share? without those it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You read the file, line by line and use something like shutil.

A quick example:

```
from shutil import copyfile 
for line in open('files.txt', 'r'): 
    filename=line.split()[0]  
    dest="folder/"+file
    copyfile(filename, dest)
```

I am sure there is a more pythonic way to do this. 
dest is where the file will end up

Edit: 
Maybe you want to use move from shutil instead.

Comment: @seánReidy. Post what you have tried in your initial question and maybe include example of your file. 
My code successfully moves a file to a new destination on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This what I have,
I Used a number of example from here,

```
listfile = open(file)
for line  in listfile:
    files  = re.search("/", files)
    shutil.copyfile (files, '/home/admin/')
```

is this someway right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code, edited it a bit here. I got it to work

listfile = open(listofFile.txt, 'r')
    dir = /home/admin/

```
for files in listfile:
    filepath=filepath.split("\n")[0]    # removing newline at the end of each line
    files = files.split("/")[-1]        # split back to the last / for the file name xxx.txt, yyy.jpeg  
    dest=str(os.path.abspath(dir))+"/"+files
    shutil.copyfile(filepath, dest)
```